# Bootstrap header is not being opaque

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap header and I have a container body.
For some reason the when i click on the hamburger menu the background is translucent.
I tried changing the opacity, header position to static / fixed / absolute, also changed background color nothing seems to work.[image]

[image]

After Clicking menu
Here is my nav bar code

```
        <div class="container">            

            <div class="navbar-header">


               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>


            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
                    <li><a href="/buyonline/sample-contract" target="_blank">View Sample Contract</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#faqsModal">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clickpoint-modal-container-form" id="clickPoint-link">Call me with a quote</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Container -->

</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide a working demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Adding navbar-fixed-top seems to have solved the problem.

Reference from: http://jsfiddle.net/menriquez/L235efdv/

Answer (score 1):

Background is not translucent, your "Step 1:..." has a higher `z-index`.

Comment: I haven't set any z-index on "step-1:..". I did try to give the header z-index ; didn't work

Comment: Well, that's the issue. If you want specific help you need to give us a working demo or a live example.

Comment: Let me try to create one, never did that before